# Using $near with $and

Tags: mongodb, geolocation

I'm trying to build a near query with additional condition:

```
query = {
    $and : [
        { address : { $near : [x, y] } },
        { available: 1 }
    ]
};

db.points.find(query)
```

It gives me an error:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index),  for: { $and: [ { ipaddr: { $near: [ -82.49412043543862, 0.0 ] } }, { available: 1.0 } ] }",
    "code" : 13038
}
```

Otherwise, the query like this works fine

```
query = { address : { $near : [x, y] }, available : 1 }
```

I need to use `$and` to build complex query.

Can I build `$near` query with `$and` keyword?

Comment: your two queries doesn't match for me, second one should be `query = { address: {$near : [x, y]} , available: 1 }`, or I'm wrong?

Comment: @RomanPekar, yes, you're right, fixed

Comment: are you sure that corrected second one works? from docs - `The $near operator requires a geospatial index. For GeoJSON points, use a 2dsphere index. For legacy coordinate pairs, use a 2d index.` I've tried it on my db and it not working

Comment: It works for me, I used '2d' indexing on address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this topic - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4572 - looks like it's a bug and it's not fixed yet..

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the greatest solution but I found a way to work around this issue. What I did is split the query into 2 parts 1) query the nearest addresses and get the objects ids 2) use it in the second query using $in operator.